# accessing files and folders other than sharepoint site's default shared documents using office365 api

Tags: sharepoint, windows-store-apps, office365

Working on windows store apps:
I am trying to access the files and folders of office365 documents library.
I can access the one drive documents as described in this link [Common file tasks using the Office 365 client library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/common-file-tasks-client-library)

But it do not provide a way to access the files and folders in other than onedrive document library.
e.g [https://my-office365-tenant.sharepoint.com/mysite/mydocumentslibrary]

However i had tried a way and it do get the files and folders other than onedrive.
I had not used any capability i created SharePointClient as given below:

```
var client = new SharePointClient(new Uri("https://my-office365-tenant.sharepoint.com/mysite"),
        async () => await AcquireTokenAsync(AuthenticationContext, "https://my-office365-tenant.sharepoint.com"));
    IPagedCollection<IItem> items = await client.Files.ExecuteAsync();
```

In this way i get the files of default "Shared Documents" document library inside "mysite", but i want to get the files and folders of another documents library "mydocumentslibrary" inside same site "mysite".

Can anyone please guide me how to do that or am i missing something? or there is anyother way to do this using office365 api only.

Answer (score 1):

I just went through the documentation of this new API, it seems the file operation is limited to the one drive, I doubt you can get file in another document library.

To get files in other document library, as you're developing windows store APPs, you  can SharePoint mobile object model or REST APIs:

1. [Overview of the SharePoint 2013 mobile object model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163797(v=office.15).aspx)
2. [Get started withthe SharePoint 2013 REST service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142380(v=office.15).aspx)

Comment: Thanks. I know that i can use, but we have to use office365 api. the options you told are our last resort.

Answer (score 1):

The APIs allows access only to default document library.  Example:

OneDrive for Business: https://{tenant}-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v1.0/me

SharePoint sites: https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/{site-path}/_api/v1.0